# Problem facing while doing pipe refresh and causing load failure in snowflake instance

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

while doing select * from internal stage I am facing

```
Invalid data encountered during decompression for file:   compression type used: 'GZIP', cause: 'data error'.
```

I want to fetch the rows of the files from the stage . The file format type I used is json and compression is 'gzip'.

But when i keep the compression as none i am facing other error

```
invalid character outside of a string: '\37' File line 1, character 1 Row 0, column $1
```

while using the put command its being used as gzip => true

Comment: You probably need to use only second format since all files are compressed by default when using PUT command. Now the error you are getting makes me think your original file is not using UTF-8 encoding, but something else and therefore you get the error. For JSON or semi-structured data we only support UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Is there anything that needs to be fixed on File Format Definition regarding UTF-8 encoding

Comment: This is probably not related to the file format, but your original file. Can you verify if your original file was created using UTF-8 encoding?